# Print output at the very beginning of the terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I would like that a script launched from the the terminal prints some texts always at the very beginning of the terminal. Is it possible ?

Comment: I'd avoid this. If the user wants output right at the top *he* will make sure that this happens. If you want to provide a complex TUI you should use the `curses` module, but this isn't necessary if you just want to show some text and ask for textual input.

Comment: My idea is to test some basic game like Sudoku using the terminal before working on a real GUI. This is for pedagogical reasons. I'll take a look at `curses`. Thanks.

Comment: Using curses you can do things like coloured text, highlighted text (underlined, bold, italic, blinking), background color, allow mouse interaction. Last year I wrote a very simple client/server draughts application using it, and the result was quite satisfying. However the API isn't as friendly as the one of a GUI library.

Comment: I know but for beginners, I think this could be a good exercise to work with the terminal. I will play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the screen at the beginning of the script:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('clear') # subprocess.call('cls', shell=True) on Windows
```